# How did 本 come to mean "this?"

Tags: meaning, kanji, etymology

I'm researching the kanji 本 for a blog post. I understand its original meaning is "root", and the other two senses, "book" and "this," are semantic shifts. I've found a couple of sources (without citations; one on Japanese StackExchange) for its sense of "book."

I'm having more trouble finding its sense of "this" as in 本学, 本件, 本状, 本品 and so on. Does anyone know how it came to be used in this way?

お手伝いありがとうございます～

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The English rendering of *this* may be somewhat misleading.  :)

The root (ha!) meaning of 本 includes a sense of *main*, and it is from this sense that the use correlating to English *this* derives: as in, "the **main** item under discussion (out of several possible items)".

Shogakukan's 国語大辞典 lists the following sense under the **II〔接頭〕** heading:

> 名詞【めいし】に付【つ】けて、今【いま】、現【げん】に問題【もんだい】にしているもの。当面【とうめん】のものである意【い】を表【あらわ】す語【ご】。当【とう】の。この。「本【ほん】講堂【こうどう】」「本【ほん】事件【じけん】」など。
>     Attached to a noun, the item now actually at issue.  Term expressing a sense that this is the immediate item.  The relevant (thing), this (thing).  Such as, "this auditorium", "this issue".

Comment: I had the slightest suspicion that would be the case. Thank you for helping out! (Also, the root puns are what this kanji's ABOUT)